# how to upgrade sqlite3 on python to the latest sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm gonna use sqlite3 version 3.7.0 or higher to able to read and write concurrently. I'm gonna use python library for that. 
Then I installed sqlite3 under ubuntu. The issue is that when I print the version of sqlite3 in python it shows the older version than the one that has been installed on the system:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.11.0'
>>>
```

As you can there the version of the installed sqlite3 in the system is 3.11.0, but, the python sqlite version is 2.6.
How can I upgrade the python sqlite to higher version?

Thanks.

Comment: check here, maybe this will help https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/upgrading-sqlite3-within-python-3/

Comment: I checked that but I couldn't really understand,